# Cannot find duplicate using search in flagging dialog?

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred, duplicate-questions, search

I came across a question ([QGIS algorithm parameter: ParameterString](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/qgis-algorithm-parameter-parameterstring#190482), question 1) which might be a duplicate of another one ([QGIS Processing - Additional Creation Parameter for GdalWarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111252/qgis-processing-additional-creation-parameter-for-gdalwarp), question 2). I was about to flag it, but I can't find question 2 in the list of suggested duplicates, even with the full title *or* keywords from the title (qgis/gdalwarp/parameter/...):

[image]

This is not the first time I face this issue. I guess this is a bug; is there a known workaround?

This is the placeholder implying that simple search is possible:

[image]

As Andre Silva noted, question 2 (older question) shouldn't be able to be selected anyway since it has not been answered (no positive score or accepted answer). So, it's kind of a bad example... However, the error message *"Your search returned no matches; please try a different search"* implies that this constraint is not the source of the issue.

Comment: it might be the `-` in the question title?

Comment: @iant: No, I removed it in the searchbox (and when looking for keywords only).

Answer (score 3):

In the type-in field at the top I always paste the URL to the duplicate rather than its title.

I had not noticed the suggestion that a search could be used, though.

Rather than a bug I think it is an in application documentation error but the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag on this should attract the SE developers to clarify whether the search option is expected to work.

Comment: Good answer, but then why does the placeholder states "**search**, or enter a question link or numeric id" (I'll illustrate this in my question)? Searching by keywords clearly doesn't work.

Comment: I've only ever used the URL or chosen from the already offered options for duplicates.

Comment: I agree with your last edit. Intuitively, one would expect from the duplicate window to filter the results according to what is typed in the searchbox. That's the reason why, until today, I overlooked the placeholder, which - as you mentioned - states that you can also use a URL.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** in response to OP's clarification in comment (but the answer is off-topic, now).

---

The reason why [QGIS algorithm parameter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190482/qgis-algorithm-parameter-parameterstring#190482) can't be flagged as duplicate from [QGIS Processing - Additional Creation Parameter for GdalWarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111252/qgis-processing-additional-creation-parameter-for-gdalwarp) is because the latter is not an **answered** question.

In Stack Exchange an answered question is considered the ones with at least one positive score answer or with an accepted answer, which is neither the case in the above example.

---

Reference in Meta Stack Exchange:

[How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

> Which question is the duplicate?
>
> .....If one of the questions is unanswered, the system won't even let you pick it as a duplicate target.

Comment: While the older question from my exemple was indeed not answered, this is not the same issue. In the case you are mentioning, I should get the following message while submitting the older question: *"This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"*. Instead, I got: *"Your search returned no matches; please try a different search"*. So that's not the issue here.

Comment: @ArMoraer. Yes, you are right. I suggest trying to edit your question to clarify/disambiguate such point. I mean, remove the part you said you are trying to flag a question which can't be flagged as dupe by the reasons I've cited.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.